# Javascript not initiating for getElementByID

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

When the user types in the address it is supposed to take the address and place its content within the hidden input fields. The javascript isnt firing and writing in the values for the input fields that are hidden.

I believe it may be javascript/jquery not executing in the correct order or I have a version conflict issue?

I have a Google Address auto complete

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
 // Need to add Lat / Long to populate field.
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name',

};

function initAutocomplete() {
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
    types: ['geocode']
  });
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = "";
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = true;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("Latitude").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
  document.getElementById("Longitude").value = place.geometry.location.lng();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initAutocomplete);
```

I have the input fields as

```
                <input type="hidden" value="" class="form-control" id="street_number" name="pnumb">
                <input type="hidden" value="" class="form-control" id="route" name="paddy">
                <input type="hidden" value="" class="form-control" id="locality" name="pcity">
                <input type="hidden" value="" class="form-control" id="administrative_area_level_1" name="pstat">
                <input type="hidden" value="" class="form-control" id="postal_code" name="pzip">
                <input type="hidden" value="" class="form-control" id="Latitude" name="plat">
                <input type="hidden" value="" class="form-control" id="Longitude" name="plong">
```

This is the javascript jquery I have at the top of my page.

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and this is what is at the bottom of the page.

```
<script src="../../plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="../../dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
```

I get the following error codes from the Console

```
1.) ReferenceError: google is not defined[Learn More]
2.) TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null[Learn More]
```

I am also having issues with trying to utilize datepicker.

I believe i have my javascript/jquery executing improperly??

Any ideas; I am horrible with Javascript/Jquery

Comment: Why are you including both jQuery 3.1.1 and also jQuery 2.2.3?

Comment: My Bootstrap is relaint on 2.2.3, where google map displaying wasnt working so I threw in 3.1.1 @Pointy

Comment: Adding another version of jQuery is almost never going to make things better.

Comment: Keep only the latest version of jQuery library, not the both.

Comment: If I remove 2.2.3 my bootstrap wont work. If I remove 3.1.1 my google maps wont work :|

Comment: you surely mean `getElementById`, not **ID**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove `country: 'long_name',` from my componentFrom variable. I didn't have an input field defined for it and it was causing it to break the js.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there are two distinct errors that might require two different analysis:

**1.) ReferenceError: google is not defined[Learn More]**

Does the first javascript code succeed the script tags? If you try to use something before declaring it you will get a reference error.

Being more explicit your code must be in this order:

```
<script src="../../plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
...
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>

<script>
    var placeSearch, autocomplete;
    // Need to add Lat / Long to populate field.
    ...

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initAutocomplete);
</script>
```

**2.) TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null[Learn More]**

Before we can tell you what the solution is we need to know where it's happening you are making several calls to document.getElementById do your browser show what line is triggering the error?

**EDIT:** I see you have not listed an input for the autocomplete control, does it appear anywhere else in your code?

You should see an input with an id="autocomplete", like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" class="form-control" id="autocomplete" name="pautocomplete">
```

Comment: My input field is there for autocomplete. However, your suggestions didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution is stated below:

**#Step-1:** Remove the 2nd jQuery version loading:

```
....
<!--<script src="../../plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
....
```

**#Step-2:** I can't see [Google MAP's Place Autocomplete Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) in your code; Include it:

```
<!-- with a callback function 'initMap' -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

**#Step-3:** Wrap up just the last line of your JS code like below:

```
function initMap(){
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initAutocomplete);
}
```

Comment: ReferenceError: google is not defined[Learn More] @reza-mamun

Comment: Did you include Google's Map API? If not then you will see that ReferenceError; @Levi